# Match every single String after character in Java (RegEx)

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I need help with this, so uhm... I have a String:

```
Hey ~firstname ~lastname today is the ~date
```

I want the program to print out this output:

```
firstname lastname date
```

in a list from the matcher (I already have a way of doing that). The only thing that I need is the regex to get my wanted output

Every help will be apprechiated

Comment: Check this RegEx:https://regex101.com/r/J8QK7A/1

Answer (score 1):

Using a matcher with the pattern `~(\S+)` we can try:

```java
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
String input = "Hey ~firstname ~lastname today is the ~date";
String pattern = "~(\\S+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
}
String output = String.join(" ", matches);
System.out.println(output);  // firstname lastname date
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, i got it working with this pattern:

```
(?<=~)\w+
```

Comment: This includes no Java code, and therefore is not a complete answer to your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).